# Delete records from listView using Sqlite in Android using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to delete records from listview  by tapping rows one after one
I* have added a **Delete button** to the cell on which I tapped to delete.
But the problem that i face here is "when I press the **delete Button** from any row it works for the first time but when I press delete button again from any other row nothing happens"

Please help me on this. I am using **kotlin** as a language

here is the adopter Code which I have used
Thanks

```
   class Adapter(con:Context, arrList:ArrayList<UserModel>): BaseAdapter()
   {
    var studentList = ArrayList<UserModel>()

    var context: Context? = null

    var myInflater: LayoutInflater? = null

    init {

        this.context    = con

        this.myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        this.studentList  = arrList
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: 
   ViewGroup?):View
    {
        var v = myInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.custome,null)
        var ConObj = studentList[position]

        var full_name : String = ConObj.name.toString()
        var textView: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.text_Name)
        textView.setText(full_name)

        var age : String? = ConObj.age
        var textAge: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.text_Age)
        textAge.text = age.toString()

        return v
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any
    {
       return studentList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long
    {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int
    {
        return studentList.size
    }

}


fun delete(v: View) 
{
  dbHelper = DataBaseHelper(this)
  var res: String = dbHelper.RemoveStudents(name!!)
  if(res=="ok") {
  var pos : Int = listView.getPositionForView(v)

  StudentList.removeAt(pos)
  StudentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
  else {
  Log.e("ab","ab"+res)
  }
  }
```

Comment: Put getPositionForView and RemoveStudents body here too.

Comment: oh boy. You should be using RecyclerView, you shouldn't need any !!s in your code, and you shouldn't do synchronous write to database on UI thread. Also most of your `var`s should be `val`s.

Comment: can you provide me any example... i am new in kotlin...